# AVAssetTrack: Audio tracks don't have a timeRange?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

With the following, and an MP3 file:

```
AVURLAsset* audio = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audioUrl options:nil];
AVAssetTrack* audioTrack = [[audio tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] 
    objectAtIndex:0];
CMTime audioDuration = audio.duration;

NSLog(@"audioDuration: %qi/%i; audioTrackDuration: %qi/%i", 
      audioDuration.value, audioDuration.timescale, 
      audioTrack.timeRange.duration.value,
      audioTrack.timeRange.duration.timescale);
```

I get:

```
audioDuration: 1513728/44100; audioTrackDuration: 0/1
```

Note that the track itself is fine when I make use of it later. I thought it might be an asynchronous key-value coding issue, but this `NSParameterAssert` seems to pass:

```
AVKeyValueStatus trStatus = [audioTrack statusOfValueForKey:@"timeRange" 
    error:&theError];
NSParameterAssert(trStatus == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded);
```

What's the deal? Is this just a quirk of the format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone coming along later: as far as I can tell, yes, `AVAssetTrack` doesn't have a time range if it's audio, and you have to use the `AVAsset` duration. Still not sure if this is only for MP3s, though, or what.